# Check what media is now playing from the command line

Tags: video, utilities, media, music-player

My desktop environment seems to know what music I am playing.  I want to be able to check that from the command line too.  Is there a tool or dbus query that will tell me what music or media is playing at the moment, and preferably what app it is playing in?

The are many possible applications for this, but my actual use case is that I want to queue up playing some music from the CLI after a one hour music set finishes playing in YouTube on Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [playerctl](https://github.com/altdesktop/playerctl) tool can show media info and control MPRIS compatible media players from the command-line.

Install using apt:

`apt install playerctl`

Example:

```
# playerctl status
Playing
# playerctl -l
chromium.instance4220
# playerctl metadata
chromium mpris:length              3902621000
chromium mpris:trackid             '/org/chromium/MediaPlayer2/TrackList/Track20DA46A8C7E420D133C1548901D59CB1'
chromium xesam:album               
chromium xesam:artist              Kaskade
chromium xesam:title               Kaskade LIVE At The Golden Gate Bridge | San Francisco , CA
```

The script for what I wanted:

```
(while [ `playerctl status` != Stopped ]; do sleep 5; done; mpv *)
```

I found this info here: [How to control music players from the Linux command-line](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/control-music-players-from-the-linux-command-line/)

Here's the manpage: [playerctl(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/playerctl/playerctl.1.en.html)